# write on two EditText differently android

Tags: android, input, android-edittext

I need to resolve this, I have two Edit Texts one named Edit(X) and Edit(Y), so, I can write and set the length of inputs in the Edit(X), but when I want to do the same in the other simply I can not, because I get the same value of Edit(X), how I can set the Edit(x) for example only two 6 digits and finish writing then pass to the Edit(Y) and start writing, a new input independently of Edit(X). here some of my code.

```
private class BtnListener implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View view) {
       switch (view.getId()) {
           case R.id.btnNum0Id:
           case R.id.btnNum1Id:
           case R.id.btnNum2Id:
           case R.id.btnNum3Id:
           case R.id.btnNum4Id:
           case R.id.btnNum5Id:
           case R.id.btnNum6Id:
           case R.id.btnNum7Id:
           case R.id.btnNum8Id:
           case R.id.btnNum9Id:
                String inDigit = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
                String inDiget = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
                if (inStr.equals("0")) {
                    inStr = inDigit; 
                } else {
                    inStr += inDigit;
                }
                if(inCtr.equals("0")){
                    inCtr = inDiget;
                } else {
                    inCtr += inDiget;
                }
                editX.setText(inStr);
                //editY.setText(inCtr);
                editX.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                        button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                //String input = editX.getText().toString();
                                // String toEditText1 = input.substring(0,2); 
                                // editZ.setText(toEditText1);
                                //String toEditText2 = input.substring(2);
                                //inputContent2.setText(toEditText2);  
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                    }
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                        if(s.length() == 4){
                            button2.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {          
                                public void onClick(View v){
                                    editY.requestFocus();
                                    editY.setText(inStr);
                                }
                            });
                        }else{
                        }
                   }
                });
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Quite honestly, this is extremely poor formatting of the code and you expect everyone to read it. **Pro Tip** Fix up your formatting if you want others to help you! I have re-edited the code and notice a lot of mistakes. Compare it with the original!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is to use Edit(X).addTextChangedListener(...)
and inside it call Edit(Y).requestFocus() when the text on Edit(X) have the size you want.

Also use android:maxLength="6" on your xml file.